# Show that I is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-13}]$ be the smallest subring of
>   $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{-13}$ and let the
>   ideal $I = \left<2,\sqrt{-13}\right>$. Show that $I$ is a principal ideal.

I have earnestly tried to prove this problem, but I can't solve it. Is it that there would be someone who could help me at this level?

Comment: What exactly is required (by definition) to show $I$ is a principal ideal?  How would you expect to show this definition is satisfied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x=(2-\sqrt{ -13})(2+\sqrt {-13})=4+13=17\in I$ so $1=17-16=x-8*2\in I$ and $I=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]$.

Comment: I understand roughly that as $1$ is in $I$, then $I = Z[\sqrt{-13}]$, but could you detail your argumentation? Some element are questioning for me...

Comment: @RobertDavis $17$ is obtained by multiplying two elements in $I$ and is thus in $I$ again since $I$ is multiplicatively closed. Then 1 is obtained by subtracting $16=2\times 8$ (which is obviously in $I$) from $17$, so is also in $I$ because $I$ is a vector space by nature.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to the other answer:
$$1=7*2+\sqrt{-13}\sqrt{-13} \in I$$